# How can I reload the tableview from another viewController when I add a new value?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I already tried the answers here at StackOverFlow with the same question as mine, but it didn't work.

Here is my story board.

[Story Board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG0wX.png)

Here is the code for my `ViewController`

```
var people = [Person]()

@IBOutlet weak var patientView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let fetchReq: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()

    do{
        let people = try PersistenceService.context.fetch(fetchReq)
        self.people = people
        self.patientView.reloadData()
    }catch{

    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    patientView.reloadData()
}
```

and here is the code of my `TableViewController`

```
var people = [Person]()

@IBOutlet weak var patientName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var patientAge: UITextField!

@IBAction func btnAdd(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let person = Person(context: PersistenceService.context)
    person.name = patientName.text
    person.age = Int16(patientAge.text!)!
    PersistenceService.saveContext()
    self.people.append(person)

}

@IBAction func btnClear(_ sender: UIButton) {

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

The problem is that when I add a person, and go back to the main ViewController, the table won't reload. However, when I close the app and open again the data will be fetch and reloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Put the fetch request in the viewWillAppear and remove it from the viewDidLoad. Tell me if it works.

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let fetchReq: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()

        do{
            let people = try PersistenceService.context.fetch(fetchReq)
            self.people = people
            self.patientView.reloadData()
        }catch{

        }
         patientView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: @Tonzkie I changed

Comment: Gosh! Thank you so much. I've been trying to figure this out for hours before I do ask here at StackOverFlow. But I didn't get it. Viola it's just that simple. +commend.